# What should I back up in addition to the .pst file when reinstalling Outlook 2003?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, reinstall

When I reinstall Outlook 2003 I will obviously back up the .pst file to have my contacts, email etc. in the new installation. However, last time I saved only the .pst, this apparently did not include my email account settings (all of which are POP3 accounts), as the accounts list was empty afterwards.

I was therefore wondering where account information is stored, so I could back it up was well. Also, is there anything else (registry settings, settings file on disk somewhere) that would be worth keeping for the new installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides that, you may want to keep the recent auto-complete list, here are instructions for cleaning that list - but you may use that file as a backup [found here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/outlook-2003/clear-the-auto-complete-email-address-cache-in-outlook/)

Comment: +1, I've had users complain that their address book is gone when restoring an outlook backup because they didn't actually have anything in their address book, everything was just in their autocomplete history.